# Unable to select installed openbox window manager theme

Tags: themes, openbox

I am running lubuntu 20.04 lts

I have downloaded a WM theme for openbox from "Pling". The themes that I had previously downloaded were .tar.gz files. This theme was a .7z file.
I have moved the file to the /usr/share/themes directory and extracted it, but when I try to select the theme in the Window Manager Preferences it does not appear.

[image: ls of /usr/share/themes]

The image above is an ls of the /usr/share/themes
I noticed the .xbm files, but I don't know what to do with them, they were not there before the extraction of the .7z file.

Answer (score 1):

solution:

When I did the extraction of MacOS-Dark.7z by `sudo 7za e MacOS-Dark.7z` ir extracted all the files into the /usr/share/themes directory.
In order for this theme to work we need to put all the ".xbm files" into the **openbox-3** directory and the openbox-3 directory into the **MacOS-Dark** directory.

We do this by `sudo mv -v close.xbm desk_toggled.xbm desk.xbm iconify.xbm max_toggled.xbm max_toggles.xbm max.xbm shade_toggled.xbm shade.xbm themerc openbox-3`

To move the **openbox-3** directory into the **MacOS-Dark** directory we do: `sudo mv -v openbox-3 MacOS-Dark`

Then the **MacOS-Dark** theme should apear in the WM preferences menu.

**note**: if you install a window manager in the `/usr/share/themes` directory it will be available system-wide. If you want the theme you're trying to install to be user-wise you need to install it in the `~/.themes/` directory.